# With Elixir/Phoenix (0.10.0), how do I set the port based on the PORT environment variable in a release?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In `config/test.exs`, I have the following lines:

```
config :youli, Youli.Endpoint,
  http: [port: System.get_env("PORT") || 4001
```

When I run `mix release`, untar the release, and run the app with PORT=4242, it runs on port 4001 instead. Grepping a bit, I found that it's hard-coded that way in `releases/0.0.3/sys.config`.

How can I get my release to run with the port set from the environment?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of `System.get_env("PORT")`, use `{:system, "PORT"}`:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/phoenix/config/test.exs b/phoenix/config/test.exs
index 10cea91..617f34c 100644
--- a/phoenix/config/test.exs
+++ b/phoenix/config/test.exs
@@ -1,7 +1,7 @@
 use Mix.Config

  config :youli, Youli.Endpoint,
  -  http: [port: System.get_env("PORT") || 4001]
  +  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}]
```

The documentation for this is in `lib/phoenix/endpoint.ex` in the Phoenix source.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `{:system, "PORT"}` or `System.get_env("PORT")`.

Comment: It does work for me with both Phoenix 0.17.0 and 1.0.0.

Comment: You are right. Idk why I got this issue. I'll check the reason for that and report an issue.